# Unable to use SPField.setValue() on rich text multiline column on dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

On load, I am able to set the text value.

But set value does not work when code is triggered by a dropdown change event. Am sure that dropdown change event had been triggered as function was able to change the text of another single line field.

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var activity = SPUtility.GetField('Going');
    var showOrHide = function()

    {
        var activity = activity.GetValue();
        var DL_sys_time = SPUtility.GetField('Time');

        if (activityVal == 'Yes')
        {
            SPUtility.ShowSPField('Time');
            DL_sys_time.setValue('8pm');
        }
        else
        {
            SPUtility.HideSPField('Time');
            DL_sys_time.setValue('');
        }
    };

    $(activity.Dropdown).on('change',showOrHide);
}
)
```

I am using SPUtility.js (Vers: 0.14.2) downloaded from http://sputility.codeplex.com/

Realised that there are typo in my code above and amended some parts for troubleshooting:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var activity = SPUtility.GetField('Going');
    var showOrHide = function()

    {
        var activity = activity.GetValue();
        var DL_sys_time = SPUtility.GetField('Note');

        if (activityVal == 'Yes')
        {
            SPUtility.ShowSPField('Note');
            DL_sys_time.setValue('Yes');
        }
        else
        {
            SPUtility.HideSPField('Note');
            DL_sys_time.setValue('No');
        }
    };

    showOrHide();

    $(activity.Dropdown).on('change',showOrHide);
}
)
```

So when the form loads, the field 'note' is hidden. When I change the value of 'Going' to "Yes", 'Note' field is shown, but the text shown is "No".

Comment: when I get the value of the rich textbox, I shows that the value is <div></div>... could it be I need to provide some special formatting when setting the value?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `SPUtility.GetSPField` like the following:

```
var notesField = SPUtility.GetSPField("notes");
notesField.setValue("anything"); //this works on multilines of rich text field
```

From what I've seen in your code, if you're trying to set a date field, it will depend on the formatting, if it's a Date format, you can set the value for it using:

```
var dateField = SPUtility.GetSPField("DateField");
dateField.SetDate(2016,12,01);
```

If it's a DateTime, you can do the code above and add the following to set the time:

```
dateField.SetTime(10,25); //parameters (hour, minute) where 0 < hour < 23
```

Comment: Hi, SPUtility.GetSPField

Comment: Sorry, GetField() was my typo when typing out the sample codes. I was using SPUtility.GetSPField.

Pls see my amended code, I run the function during form load. Seems like it is working during form load, but not when it is triggered by the dropdownlist event.